# Creating an array from a curl - PHP

Tags: php, curl

Hey guys so I am using an API from a client and creating a request to grab information.  Now the response is a curl type:

```
    ...code....
    $url = 'apiURL';
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string );

    $output = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    $output = (array) $output;
    print_r( $output );
```

Once I print the following these are my results:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 Success 79591908 79591908 mEg0gN )
```

Each one of these values have a specific value but what I am looking for is for each value printed out to be in it's own array spot because I need to grab the printed information accordingly.

Example:

```
Array ( [0] => 1, [1] => success, ...and so forth)
```

Not to sure on how I can accomplish this, thoughts and ideas?

David

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is a string but you are forcing it to become an array.

```
$output = (array) $output;
```

This, I believe, is wrong. Accept it as a string and then you can convert it into an array of your own format later like

```
$output = curl_exec( $ch );
$outputArray=explode(" ",$output);
```

This will then explode that string on a space and put all those elements separately which were extracted from your string.

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Success
    [2] => 79591908
    [3] => 79591908
    [4] => mEg0gN
)
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/Ihdg8mIM)**

Comment: paste the output of `var_dump(curl_exec( $ch ));`

Comment: string(180) " 1 Success 79657183 79657183 t3N6od "

Comment: Then it should work for sure like it does in fiddle, I hope `$output = (array) $output;` was removed before trying it

Comment: $output = curl_exec( $ch );
 $outputArray = explode(" ",$output);
 $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
 
 print_r( $outputArray );
 var_dump(curl_exec( $ch ));
 curl_close( $ch );

Comment: @HankyPanky so any idea as to why it is not working for me?  I am doing exactly what you said.